# Как в url найти точное слово и вернуть его левую часть

Tags: python, парсер, requests, urllib

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на сайте найти нужное слово , и вернуть его левую часть.

```
    # url
    site = urllib.request.urlopen('https://scanner.tradingview.com/crypto/scan').read().decode("utf-8")
    
    # Вводим название тикера
    ticker_name = input('Введите название тикера : ').upper()
    ticker_request = [ticker_name]

    # Проверяем, существует ли такой тикер. Если существует то в принт выводим, что тикер найден

    for i in ticker_request:
        if i in site:
            print('Введенный тикер {} найден'.format(ticker_name))
            print(exchange)
        else:
            print("К сожалению тикер {} отсутствует в базе".format(ticker_name))
```

Вот по такому принципу, я нахожу сам тикер, ну не могу понять , как вернуть биржу, откуда этот тикер взят , нужно вернуть все 'точные' сопоставления введенные в input + биржа
Данные по ссылке вот такого типа

```
{"s":"GATEIO:FLMUSDT","d":[]}
```

Вот из этого текста я понимаю, как извлечь 'GATEIO', ну а как через запрос проверить существование тикера и сразу извлечь от туда название биржы , я не понимаю, в виду совсем малого опыта.

Пример того, что я хотел бы получить :

```
# В input допустим введено 'btcusdt'
data = ['BINANCE', 'FTX', 'BYBIT']
```

далее в data заносятся все биржи, где есть 'btcusdt', не 'btcusd' или 'btcusdtperp' , а именно 'btcusdt'

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример

```
import requests

res = requests.get('https://scanner.tradingview.com/crypto/scan').json()
data = []
ticker_name = 'btcusdt'.upper()
for rr in res['data']:
    rt = rr['s'].split(':')
    if rt[1] == ticker_name:
        data.append(rt[0])
print(data)

['BINANCEUS', 'FTX', 'BINGX', .... 'KUCOIN', 'OKCOIN', 'PHEMEX']
```

Comment: спасибо большое, классное решение . Обязательно его запомню